# Number of Birthdays in a Sample of People

Tags: probability

How does one calculate the expected number of birthdays that fall on a given day or during a given week, assuming random birthdays (P=1/365), and a sample of population, n?

Comment: n*p (n/365) for a day, n/52 for a week. But birthdays are not randomly distributed throughout the year...

Comment: See this fascinating analysis of birth days throughout the year by [Aki Vehtari and Andrew Gelman](http://andrewgelman.com/2012/06/19/slick-time-series-decomposition-of-the-birthdays-data/) [in the USA].

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ birthdates are randomly placed in the year, that's the same as choosing $n$ values randomly (with replacement) from $1,2,...,365$.

For a given person, there's a $p=1/365$ chance of their birthday occurring on a given day. If their birthday is on a given day, there's a contribution of 1 birthday and otherwise it's a contribution of 0 birthdays on that day. So the expected number of birthdays on a given day due to one person is $1\times p + 0 \times (1-p) = p$.

Due to [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties), with $n$ people the expected number of birthdays on any day will be $np$.

Similarly, the expected number of birthdays in a week is 7np.